# How to only get the 24 military time JavaScript

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following http://jsfiddle.net/patrolcad/hr9fxmqo/2/

I keep getting this

```
18. 21:56 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

I'm tryng to get only the first four digits, sample `00:00`:

```
$(
function(){

    $('#time').ready(function(){
              var time = new Date();                
              $('#time-holder2').val(time.toTimeString());  
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `getHours()` and `getMinutes()`

```
var time = new Date();  
console.log( time.getHours() + '' + time.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
document.getElementById("WhateverHTMLElement").innerHTML = `${h}:${m}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to extract the first 5 characters:

```
$('#time-holder2').val(time.toTimeString().slice(0, 5));
```